# Why is JBoss Post Form sending parameters in URL?

Tags: jboss, double-submit-prevention

Our JBoss form is posting the parameters in the URL instead of in the request despite being a POST form. I have confirmed that the form is post in the actual page using Firebug. Note that this is within a portlet.

We are submitting the form using javascript like:

```
function submitForm(action, time)
{
    document.getElementById("pageActionInputID").value = time;
    document.getElementById("timeSpanFormInputID").value = action;
    document.getElementById("formID").submit();
}



<form action="<portlet:actionURL></portlet:actionURL>" method="POST" id="formID">
<input type="hidden" name="pageAction" id="pageActionInputID" />
<input type="hidden" name="timeSpan" id="timeSpanFormInputID" />
</form>
```

where 'portlet' is from

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet"%>
```

Any ideas why we are getting the inputs in the URL?

Here is what the resulting markup looks like:

```
<form id="formID" method="post" action="/portal/auth/portal/myTab?action=1">
<input id="pageActionInputID" type="hidden" name="pageAction"/>
<input id="timeSpanFormInputID" type="hidden" name="timeSpan"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What does the HTML output of the form look like?

Comment: The form looks standard (see edit). I think it is because we are working in a portlet and it throws out the post/get and uses action URLs instead. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it would be great if someone could confirm it. I think the JBoss Portlet throws out post/get and uses action URLs instead.

[A descriptive article about render and action URLs](http://knol.google.com/k/matt/creating-portlet-urls-on-jboss-as/1ueb8yo1mnkcr/7#)